# Em qual plataforma a seguinte dúvida deve ser publicada?

Tags: debate

**Gostaria de fazer a pergunta abaixo mas fico em  dúvida se deveria ou não perguntá-la no SOpt, ou onde deveria postar... 
Poderiam validar por favor? Obrigado!**

> Pergunta a ser realizada, abaixo:

Pessoal, tenho uma ideia de projeto desktop e que desejo desenvolver com nodejs (desafio).

Pesquisei a respeito de como desenvolver uma aplicação desktop com esta ferramenta e tudo o que descobri é que existe um bilhão de frameworks por aí, mas nenhum que vi, me entregou nada parecido com o que desejo...

Gostaria de uma forma relativamente fácil de fazer um .exe com Nodejs e como ele faz isso, por exemplo: ele trabalha meio que como um app híbrido, onde o navegador é aberto para executar o app?

**Obs.:** Ainda não tenho nenhum fonte. Dependendo da resposta que obtiver aqui irei mudar a tecnologia de desenvolvimento ou irei desenvolver em node mesmo.

Obrigado pelo auxílio.

Comment: Site errado, aqui é o [meta]. Voce deveria abrir esta pergunta no site principal.

Comment: No máximo essa pergunta pertenceria ao [pt.so], mas ainda assim acho que é ampla demais.

Comment: @Articuno, justamente. Antes de postar lá, gostaria de saber se é lá mesmo que devo postar, pois fiquei em dúvida... Essa é a ajuda que espero de vocÊs

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, Por que acha isso? Talvez a escrita da pergunta?

Comment: Você poderia criar seu próprio framework :). Chegou a ver o [electonjs](https://electronjs.org)?

Comment: @rray hummm muito interessante! Não vi ainda, mas vou ver agora. Valeu a dica...

Comment: Para definir um framework, você precisa de um problema muito bem estruturado. Para conseguirmos começar a discutir qualquer coisa, será necessário que você nos passe os detalhes do problema. Sem isso, não tem como aferir.

Comment: Eu não consegui entender exatamente o que você quer que o framework faça.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, aqui no meta não estou perguntando nada sobre framework, ainda. Esta pergunta que fiz se trata apenas de saber onde devo pergunta-lá. Entende?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, preferia não usar framework na verdade, mas a intenção é gerar um .exe. Uma aplicação desktop. Entende? Mas no momento, a minha intenção aqui é primeiramente onde postar esta pergunta

Comment: @DiegoSantos então seu problema é gerar o tal .exe? É que a sua pergunta esta bem confusa, nem consigo saber da forma que esta se faz parte do escopo do site principal, se puder explicar melhor talvez eu consiga até te indicar algo.

Comment: @DiegoSantos pra mim isso é totalmente on-topic, e tenho quase certeza que não depende de frameworks, é que os frameworks geralmente já trazem ferramentas embutidas (que são adicionais), mas estou quase certo que pode haver ferramentas stand-alone que fará isto

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, Sim desejo gerar o .exe com nodejs. De preferência, sem framworks. Talvez minha pergunta esteja confusa pois estou perguntando sobre outra pergunta rs. Hoje desenvolvo com .net. Sei bem o que é necessário para desenvolver uma app desktop com essa tecnologia. Gostaria de fazer uma app simples com nodejs, para desktop.

Comment: Só pra constar, .exe é coisa de windows, em Mac o esquema é outro (é o .app ou arquivo marcado como executavel) e no Linux é um arquivo marcado como executavel.

Comment: Vocês leram a pergunta?

Comment: Diego, acho que eu já respondi, sim me parece on-topic e não é algo que dependerá de FWs, mas sim de alguma ferramenta, e considero on-topic porque ferramentas para desenvolvedores faz parte do topico.

Comment: @ramaral li e esta meio confusa, ao menos pra mim. Ou no minimo ampla, pergunta mais de uma coisa.

Comment: Eu editei. Coloquei a minha pergunta a ser respondida aqui em negrito. O que está abaixo é o conteúdo a ser avaliado. Melhorou assim?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento O OP quer saber se uma pergunta feita nos termos(com o texto) colocado por debaixo de `Pergunta...` está dentro do escopo do SOpt.

Comment: @ramaral sim, isso eu entendi desde o começo, tanto que eu nem votei para fechar, só foi o Anderson e o Maniero. Talvez o problema foi o titulo da pergunta que **não** é muito intuitivo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu comentei porque todos os comentários eram sobre a suposta pergunta e não sobre a pergunta efectiva. Concordo consigo em que o título está longe de expressar o pretendido.

Comment: O meu não, o meu primeiro é este https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6936/software-desktop-com-nodejs?noredirect=1#comment26729_6936, e não vejo isto como dizendo que o local foi errado, ao contrário, eu gostaria que o autor melhorasse o que perguntou no Meta para tornar mais claro a necessidade... A pergunta dele é se pode perguntar no site principal, ou seja se é escopo, e para isto preciso entender melhor o que ele deseja perguntar.

Comment: Obrigado pelo auxílio. Eu melhorei o título, para que o entendimento seja feito de uma melhor forma.

Comment: @DiegoSantos acho que ficou bom agora, só essa parte de plataforma que talvez (não tenho certeza) pode soar errado. Mas é melhor ver a opinião dos demais.

Comment: Bom, vi que minha pergunta trouxe muita repercussão aqui.Acredito que deveria postar minha dúvida (A sobre o Nodejs) no SOpt, claro que mais lapidada.
Agradeço aos que me ajudaram e pela vontade!

Comment: @DiegoSantos por mim é on-topic, porque pergunta de uma ferramenta de desenvolvimento e podem surgir boas respostas, só tem que tomar cuidado para torna-la ampla demais, se acaso ocorrer, divida em diferentes perguntas.

Comment: Valeu @GuilhermeNascimento!!

Comment: Inclusive achei duas perguntas no SOen que são basicamente a mesmas duvidas que a sua :)

Comment: Opa, vou consultar lá. Obrigado1!

Comment: Se perguntar no SOpt eu já ia formular uma resposta XD

Comment: Vou perguntar sim Guilherme. Muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda. Acho que esse conteúdo deveria estar lá. Valeuu